# Null list vs. empty list in SQL backed REST API

Tags: sql, list, rest, nullable

I'm exposing a SQL database through a REST API.

Say I have a `User` model with this schema:

```
User
- name (string, required)
- age (int, optional)
- friends (list of User, optional)
```

When a client `POST`s a `User` without the `age` and `friends` fields, the `User` is stored in the SQL database with `age` as `null` and no "friend" relation to any other `User`.

When the client `GET`s the user back, my API returns no value for `age` and an empty array for the `friends` key.

```
POST /users/
{"name": "Chuck"}
GET /users/chuck
{"name": "Chuck", "friends": []}
```

I feel weird about returning a value that is not exactly what was sent by the client, even if functionally, it holds the same meaning.

But I don't see any way to differentiate "no list" and "empty list" in the database.

This is related to SQL, because in MongoDB, for instance, the document would be stored differently in "empty list" and "missing list" cases, so it is possible to return exactly what was sent.

Is there a commonly accepted guideline about this?

Should I just let it go?

I can mark the field as `default=[]` in the API so that at least the client can't claim he's surprised about this. But this looks like a workaround.

I'm using Python, SQLAlchemy for the database and Marshmallow for the API serialization/deserialization but I don't think this is Python specific.

Comment: Just let go. If null list and empty list mean semantically the same thing for your case it should not matter. In fact I think it's better to have empty collection instead of null one.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an implementation thing. If no age is specified and none returned, then if no friends are specified then none should be returned. The empty array is just how 'no friends' is implemented by the database. Your client doesn't care about the database but cares about consistency. There's no reason to return an empty friends array other than that's what the database might produce.

I'd say be consistent and save the client some work, checking whether the array is empty. If there's no friends array there's nothing for the client to check but importantly, it's consistent with how other non existent attributes are (not) returned.

However, to answer:

> not exactly what was sent by the client

that's largely irrelevant as the client is interacting with your domain, rather than telling your backend to save data exactly the way it wants it to be saved. If your domain specifies that a user will have an empty friends array if none are specified then that's what gets returned, an empty array but it goes against consistency as the user has no age but an empty age isn't returned. What is an empty age? nil? Perhaps age should be a required attribute? If so, the problem goes away.

Comment: Consistency is my point. I don't want to return `age=null` and `null` for all the other fields of the model/resource. And I don't want to make them all required. When no data is provided for an optional field, I'd like to return nothing, not `null`. (https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/285010/null-vs-missing-key-in-rest-api-response)

Comment: Ideally I would like to return no `friends` field if the user sent none, and return `[]` if the user sent `[]`. Except I have no way of knowing what he sent since both are stored identically. And maybe the problem is not that those two cases are expressed the same way in the DB, since they hold the same meaning. My only problem is consistency. Marking the field as `default=[]` sort of solves this as the client is supposed to expect `[]` anyway.

Comment: depends how you interpret 'no data'. Is no friends field from the client the same as an empty array of friends? I'd say yes, they both mean 'no friends'. How that's implemented in the database should be separate from how you return a representation of your domain object (user)

Comment: "Is no friends field from the client the same as an empty array of friends? I'd say yes," Indeed. "How that's implemented in the database should be separate from how you return a representation of your domain object (user)" Absolutely. I guess I'm just facing a "limitation" of my "framework": by design, all lists default to "empty list" and can't be stored as None/null and returned missing like flat attributes/fields.